# How do i join all data in 1 col of a table2 to table1 whilst keeping non matching data in table1

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to join information to my table 1 from table 2 without losing any data in table1. I have tried inner, full outer, left and right joins but all bring same result - removing some table1 data rows.

table 1

```
Col1, Col2, col3
1, mary, null
2, john, null
3, sally, 25
4, barry, 15
```

table 2

```
Col1, Col2
2, fireman, 1
3, office, 2
4, teacher, 3
```

desired result

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1, mary, null, null
2, john, null, fireman
3, sally, 25, office
4, barry, 15, teacher
```

what i get;

```
2, john, null, fireman
3, sally, 25, office
4, barry, 15, teacher
```

With my query

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from table1 left join col2 on table1.col1=table2.col1 order by table2.col3 asc
```

Comment: Did we solve your problem?

Comment: You did indeed. Apologies for un-prompt response, i was unexpectedly offline. My issue was (and i didn't show in simplified case problem above) was i was filtering on a col that was null for some lines a which made it appear my Left join wasn't working. You answers helped me see the issue clearly, thanks a mill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   T1.col1, 
         T1.col2, 
         T1.col3, 
         T2.col2 AS col4
FROM     Table1 T1
         LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
             ON T1.col1 = T2.col1 
ORDER BY T2.col2 ASC
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7bd99/2)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've built it according to your desired solution:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col2 AS col4 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
ORDER BY t2.col2 ASC
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d015c/2])

You could review the fiddle above.

good luck!