# How to join multiple tables by selecting the whole values in the first table and some values in the second table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have been having problems with my sql query. I am trying to fetch all the values from a user table and sum the loan they have collected this month on the Loan table but I am getting error every time I run the query.

Here is the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM customer c 
     INNER JOIN(SELECT SUM(loan_amt) as lamt, disb_date, ac_no FROM loans GROUP BY ac_no) AS l ON c.cust_no=l.ac_no
```

Please, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i join all data in 1 col of a table2 to table1 whilst keeping non matching data in table1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094865/how-do-i-join-all-data-in-1-col-of-a-table2-to-table1-whilst-keeping-non-matchin)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT c.*,l.lamt FROM customer c INNER JOIN(SELECT SUM(loan_amt) as lamt, disb_date, ac_no FROM loans GROUP BY ac_no,disb_date) AS l ON c.cust_no=l.ac_no
```

Comment: @KristikaTalwar, I received this error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'loans.disb_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you all for your precious time.

Comment: check my edit. either remove disb_date from select list or add this to group by clause @fagbemiayodele

Comment: Thanks it worked but when i wanted to add another like say four rows from the loans table it output error. Would I keep on grouping them?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting more columns in the `select` than are in the `group by`.  So:

```
SELECT c.*, l.lamt
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(loan_amt) as lamt, ac_no
      FROM loans
      GROUP BY ac_no
     ) l
     ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no;
```

Note that I also changed the join to `LEFT JOIN`.  Your question specifically says "all rows", and that suggests even rows without loans.

Comment: When I wanted to add another like say four rows from the loans table it output error. Would I keep on grouping them?

Comment: @fagbemiayodele . . . You should ask new questions as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree Gordon linoff. It's because your `group by` doesn't include disb_date even though it's in the select part of the sub-query. However, you don't want to add it in your group by because it probably won't produce the correct results.

I'm guessing you want the disb_date because you want retrieve loans for a particular month. Is this correct? If so, I would add a where clause to Gordon's solution:

```
SELECT c.*, l.lamt
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(loan_amt) as lamt, ac_no
      FROM loans WHERE disb_date BETWEEN <insert date> AND <insert date>
      GROUP BY ac_no
     ) l
     ON c.cust_no = l.ac_no;
```

This will bring up the sum of the loans which were only collected for your specified month.